# How to install Grails in Eclipse Kepler 4.3 and how to run Grails applications using it?

Tags: grails

I am unable to deploy Grails into Eclipse Kepler 4.3. I would like to know whether it is possible to deploy Grails into Eclipse Kepler 4.3 version. If yes, then how to develop applications using it. If no, then what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If by deploying Grails you mean to create an environment for building Groovy and Grails application, then you need to install:

> Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS)

Most likely there is an installation for Eclipse Kepler (4.3).

After that it's a matter of creating new Grails/Groovy application. Make sure you follow Grails  documentations. They are my best friends in terms of learning API.

Comment: I had already downloaded GGTS but I am unable to get the information regarding installation for Eclipse Kepler and deploying grails into it... @BurtBeckwith... please help me in installing it.

Comment: The easiest way is to click on Help -> Eclipse Marketplace... and in search box type "grails". Find Groovy/Grails Tool Suite for Kepler and click on the install button.

Comment: You don't install GGTS into Kepler or another Eclipse, it is Eclipse already, with the Grails and Groovy plugins pre-installed (along with a few others, e.g. Git). After installing GGTS you can add any other Eclipse plugins you want just like in any Eclipse distro. If you click the "all versions" link or go to http://spring.io/tools/ggts/all you can see that there's a GGTS for 4.3.1 (Kepler) or 3.8.2